# OpenMP Producer-Consumer unexpected result

Tags: c, multithreading, openmp, producer-consumer

I am working on a simple producer-consumer problem, using OpenMP in C.

My program creates 4 threads, two of which are consumers and two producers. Each producer places a character in a buffer, and the consumers just print the character.

My aim is to synchronize the producers/consumers so that each producer will produce the next in order character of the alphabet and each consumer will print the next in order character that is placed in the buffer.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <omp.h>

#define SIZE 5
#define NUMITER 26


char buffer[SIZE];
int nextin = 0;
int nextout = 0;
int count = 0;
int empty = 1;
int full = 0;
int i,j;

void put(char item)
{
    buffer[nextin] = item;
    nextin = (nextin + 1) % SIZE;

    count++;
    if (count == SIZE)
        full = 1;
    if (count == 1) // buffer was empty
        empty = 0;
}


void producer(int tid)
{
    char item;
    while( i < NUMITER)
    {
        #pragma omp critical
        {
            item = 'A' + (i % 26);
            put(item);
            i++;
            printf("%d Producing %c ...\n",tid, item);
        }
        sleep(1);
    }
}


char get()
{
    char item;

    item = buffer[nextout];
    nextout = (nextout + 1) % SIZE;
    count--;
    if (count == 0) // buffer is empty
        empty = 1;
    if (count == (SIZE-1))
        // buffer was full
        full = 0;
    return item;
}


void consumer(int tid)
{
    char item;
    while(j < NUMITER )
    {
        #pragma omp critical
        {
            j++;
            item = get();
            printf("%d ...Consuming %c\n",tid, item);
        }
    sleep(1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int tid;
    i=j=0;
    #pragma omp parallel firstprivate(i,j) private(tid) num_threads(4) 
    {
       tid=omp_get_thread_num();

       if(tid%2==1)
       {
           producer(tid);
       }
       else
       {
           consumer(tid);
       }
    }
}
```

And this is the output :

```
0 Producing A ...
2 Producing B ...
1 ...Consuming A
3 ...Consuming B
1 ...Consuming  <---- notice empty
0 Producing C ...
3 ...Consuming  <---- notice empty
2 Producing D ...
2 Producing E ...
3 ...Consuming E
0 Producing F ...
1 ...Consuming F
2 Producing G ...
3 ...Consuming G
0 Producing H ...
1 ...Consuming H
3 ...Consuming D
2 Producing I ...
0 Producing J ...
1 ...Consuming J
3 ...Consuming F
2 Producing K ...
0 Producing L ...
1 ...Consuming L
3 ...Consuming H
2 Producing M ...
0 Producing N ...
1 ...Consuming N
3 ...Consuming J
2 Producing O ...
0 Producing P ...
1 ...Consuming P
3 ...Consuming L
2 Producing Q ...
0 Producing R ...
1 ...Consuming R
2 Producing S ...
3 ...Consuming S
0 Producing T ...
1 ...Consuming T
3 ...Consuming P
2 Producing U ...
0 Producing V ...
1 ...Consuming V
2 Producing W ...
3 ...Consuming W
0 Producing X ...
1 ...Consuming X
2 Producing Y ...
3 ...Consuming Y
0 Producing Z ...
1 ...Consuming Z
```

Those empty lines that have not printed a character indicate that I dont achieve the synchronization that I should.
What am I missing?

Thank you in advance for any help or ideas.

Comment: `for ( i < NUMITER)` what is that?

Comment: Its a mistake.It is meant to be a 'while(i<NUMITER)'. Thank you I will change it now. (I made the mistake transferring the code so I have it the correct way when executing)

Comment: Your code has some data races. Try to profile it with `valgrind --tool=helgrind ./program` or something similar (Intel Thread Checker,
Oracle Studio Thread Analyzer, etc.)

Comment: I can't reproduce your results. Can you post the **exact** code which triggers this issue if convenient? Also `(NULL)` as a result of `printf` (in `glibc` at least) seems to be caused when a null pointer is passed while the format specifier is `%s`. Your code have no `%s` and I don't think `%c` would generate things like `(NULL)`.

Comment: @JIghtuse Thank you for your help and quick response, but I had no luck with the profiling. I didn't understand much. I found the solution though after checking the OpenMP spec, it was a rather dumb mistake that I made.

Comment: @starrify you are correct, (NULL) came after an edit I made in some stage. The exact code is the above code , I will correct the results and I will answer my question as soon as possible. I cant do it yet since I am a new member.

Comment: Your question is inconsistent after your last edit. It says _"Those (NULL) values indicate..."_ but there are no such values in the output shown. If you'd like to answer your question, wait until you have the necessary privileges to do so, or **append** code changes and new sample outputs to the end of the original question.

Comment: @HristoIliev If you notice the 5th and 7th line of the output you will see that there is no character printed. How else should I call this absence of 'output' if not NULL ?

Comment: It could happen sometimes that outputs from multiple threads get mixed together. Put something like `<---- notice empty` on the lines that you consider wrong instead. Or write _"The lines with empty values after `...` indicate..."_. In any case, keep your edits consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So @Jlghtuse was correct, there were data races and that was because of mistaken declarations of the critical areas.

You see I declared my critical areas:

```
void consumer(int tid)
{
    char item;
    while(j < NUMITER )
    {
        #pragma omp critical
        {
            j++;
            item = get();
            printf("%d ...Consuming %c\n",tid, item);
        }
    sleep(1);
    }
}
```

and

```
void producer(int tid)
{
    char item;
    while( i < NUMITER)
    {
        #pragma omp critical
        {
            item = 'A' + (i % 26);
            put(item);
            i++;
            printf("%d Producing %c ...\n",tid, item);
        }
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

That resulted in consumers not having access into other consumers critical area but produces had and vice versa. The solution was rather simple, I just had to add a common name for the critical areas and now a critical area for a consumer is critical for a producer too, and vice versa.

This is the correct code for declaring the critical areas:

```
#pragma omp critical (CRIT)
```